# SQL error after updating CakePHP3 (minor version upgrade)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, cakephp-3.x

After updating CakePHP I'm getting the following error on my development machine:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'stockapi.Products.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The SQL command is: `SELECT Products.id AS Products__id FROM products Products WHERE Products.delivery_id in (:c0) GROUP BY ean`

It seems to be working fine on my production server, but not on my OSX development computer.
I think its because I have `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` turned on on my computer. I could of course turn this off, but I would like to make my code comply with only full group by. What do I need to change in my SQL code?

Comment: Is the statement in the question title true? Question body suggests it's all due to enabling `only_full_group_by` which, apparently, is just not supported by CakePHP (either this or previous version).

Comment: Your SQL statement is invalid.  The SELECT clause can only contain columns named in the GROUP BY clause and aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), etc).